# Свойство repeat и спрайты: проблема

Tags: position, вёрстка

Задача такая - указать позиции нужной картинки из спрайта и размножить ее в диве (их 2 - один вертикальный, другой горизонтальный). Нарисовал картинку для более ясного понимания всей картины:

[image: объяснение]

Я как только не эксперементировал с `repeat x,y; background pos.` :(
Help me guys!

Вот [пример](http://jsfiddle.net/Tech/ju3pW/), задача: замостить крестиками весь нижний див (вместо крестиков будет иная картинка, но это всего-лишь пример).

Answer (score 1):

Укажите конкретные параметры высоты и ширины - и проблема пропадет(ответ к пояснениям на картинке).

**Добавлено**:
Если уж ну вообще никак не получается, то вынесите в отдельные файлы злосчастные картинки и не дурите себе голову.

**Добавлено**:
Черт, какая-то засада получается! Делайте так, как я написал выше.

Comment: + background-repeat: no-repeat;  
(это само собой, разумеется)

Comment: @metazet
нет, вы не поняли. Мне наоборот надо размножить нужную картинку в DIV фактически заполнив его

Comment: Значит уставанливайте соответствующий background-repeat для дивов, repeat-x для горизонтального повторения и repeat-y для вертикального.

Comment: @metazet 
не могли бы поподробнее?

Comment: Куда уж тут подробнее...  

    #horizontalDiv{background-repeat: repeat-x;}
    #verticalDiv{background-repeat: repeat-y;}  
Ну и соответствующие background-position и width с height

Comment: Что-то мне подсказывает, что не верно указываете [background-position][1]!


  [1]: http://htmlbook.ru/css/background-position

Comment: @metazet http://jsfiddle.net/Tech/ju3pW/ вот к примеру кривой вариант нужного мне, задача: замостить крестиками весь нижний див. Я буду очень благодарен вам если вы найдте решение из этой возможно простой проблемы. Мой затуманенный разум мешает мне решить это самостоятельно, как бы я не бился :)